# can i change printer_write in another language?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to print a page. I use `printer_select_font` to change the font and then I use `printer_draw_text` to print, but it is slow.

So my questions is, can I change `printer_write` in another language? Thanks in advance.

I use this code:

```
$handle = printer_open();
printer_start_doc($handle, "My Document");

$handle = printer_open();
printer_set_option($handle,PRINTER_FORMAT_CUSTOM,'2x2');

$handle = printer_open();
printer_start_doc($handle, "My Document");
printer_start_page($handle);
$font = printer_create_font("Saumil_guj2", 15, 9, 100, false, false, false, 0);
printer_select_font($handle, $font);
$dyna=10;
if($_SESSION['slip_setting']['soc_name']=="full")
{
    printer_draw_text($handle, $_SESSION['society_info']['soc_name_eng'], 10, $dyna);
    $tot=$dyna+15;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i researched on this topic but it came out that there is no support for **printer_write** in any other language.it can not be changed in other language.it only support printer default language.